# Laravel 7: Read single resource not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i'm new in Laravel and i'm building a simple user registration system.

When i access edit route, it seems that it's not getting the requested resource data.

I did some research and all the stuff i read, is already in place. Am i missing something?

web.php(router):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// USER PAGES:
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

UsersController.php:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Users;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Users  $users
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Users $users)
    {
        return view('dashboard.user.edit', compact('users'));
    }

/**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Users  $users
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Users $users)
    {
        $users->delete();

        return redirect()->route('users.index')
            ->with('success', "User was removed successfully.");
    }
}
```

edit.blade.php:

```php
<form id="user-data" action="{{route('users.update',$users->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')

  <input type="file" id="input-user-photo" name="user_avatar" style="display: none;">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">User Data</div>
        <div class="card-body card-block">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
              </div>
              <input type="text" id="username" name="name" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" value="{{$users->name}}">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" value="{{$users->email}}">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
              </div>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password (For not changing, leave it blank)" class="form-control">
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon">
                 <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
               </div>
               <input type="password" id="password-confirmation" placeholder="Password Confirmation" class="form-control">
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-actions form-group">
             <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">Cancel</a>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Submit</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </form>
```

On Screen (URL: /users/{{$anyUserId}}/edit):

[image]

Also, when i access destroy route it reaches the right controller's method "destroy" and even redirects properly, with success message, as specified in the method, but the resource is not deleted from database. In both cases, it seems to me that it is not finding the resource to inject as parameter within these methods.

Any clues? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the resource name is `users` the route parameter would be `user` (singular). The route parameters are by default the singular version of the resource name when using resource routing.

For implicit route model binding to work you need the typehinted parameter of your methods to match the route parameter:

```
public function edit(Users $user)

public function destroy(Users $user)
```

Side note: usually Model names are singular and their tables are plural.

Comment: Ty! This is the correct answer. What is weird is that i remember that when i generated this controller with artisan, it created these methods parameters as (User $users) which is wrong, then i changed it to (Users $users) which made it work partially and now that i changed to (Users $user) as you said, it is working fully. Thank you!